# spring serializes every attribute in class (lazy loading?)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, lazy-loading, fetch

I got issues with my model classes. For example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "kreis", catalog = "quanto_portal")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="idKreis")
public class Kreis implements java.io.Serializable {

private Integer idKreis;
private String kreisname;
private Set<Ort> orts = new HashSet<Ort>(0);

public Kreis() {
}

public Kreis(String kreisname) {
    this.kreisname = kreisname;
}

public Kreis(String kreisname, Set<Ort> orts) {
    this.kreisname = kreisname;
    this.orts = orts;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)

@Column(name = "idKreis", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getIdKreis() {
    return this.idKreis;
}

public void setIdKreis(Integer idKreis) {
    this.idKreis = idKreis;
}

@Column(name = "kreisname", nullable = false, length = 50)
public String getKreisname() {
    return this.kreisname;
}

public void setKreisname(String kreisname) {
    this.kreisname = kreisname;
}

//@JsonManagedReference(value="kreis-ort")
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "kreis")
public Set<Ort> getOrts() {
    return this.orts;
}

public void setOrts(Set<Ort> orts) {
    this.orts = orts;
}
```

When I query for an "Kreis"-Object it also internally querys for the dependent "Orts", although Lazy-Loading is set. Next, in "Ort"-class a statement for dependent "Kreis"-objects is done (cause it's an attribute of Ort; Lazy-Loading is set). If "Ort" has more dependent classes/attributes for example "Persons", even the whole "Person"-class is loaded. **Can anyone tell me why? Do I need to set a property in Spring or initializing a specific bean?**

So far I need to ignore (with @JsonIgnoreProperties) every attribute that references to another class. I think thats wrong, cause lazy-loading should effect that dependet objects are only loaded, if I ask for it.

Answer (score 1):

`LAZY` means lazily loaded *from the database when the collection is accessed*. As soon as Jackson starts serializing the object, it reads all the fields, including the `orts` field, which triggers the lazy loading.

If you're wanting to only serialize certain fields, then you probably want to return a projection of some sort from your controller; the just-released Spring Data Hopper M1 supports returning projections from Spring Data repositories, and [you can also use Jackson projections](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29335264/1189885) if you need to deal with the full entity object in your controller.

Comment: Ok, so the "issue" is the serialization. Actually, I would like to have only the orts that belong to the kreis and not all other dependent objects (e.g. person). So my aim is kind of reducing the serialization-depth.

Comment: So maybe you're wanting to limit the serialization of some property on `Ort` instead. At some point, you may need to come up with a dedicated DTO class, but I'd check the brand-new Hopper projection support; you could do this with composed interfaces.

Comment: I never heard about "Hopper projection" and I totally dont know what it is or does.

I have my DTO which contains the right values, but nevertheless it asks for too much data or retrieves too much data.

As I said, at the moment, I reduce the data by @JsonIgnoreProperties, **but it doesn't seem to be the best way to do it**

Comment: @Andy It doesn't seem like you read my entire answer; searching for Spring Data Hopper would have led you directly to [the release announcement](http://spring.io/blog/2016/02/12/spring-data-release-train-hopper-m1-released).