# Jackson from json to class via interface

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I have class

```
public class Car() {

  @JsonProperty("type")
  private String type;

  @JsonProperty("configuration")
  @JsonDeserialize(using = AlertRuleConfigurationDeserialize.class)
  private Configuration config;
}
```

Configuration is interface which have 3 classes. How can I deserialize `Car` from json via type? If I have `String type = "type1"`, I should deserialize to `ConfigurationImplFirst`, etc. I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19379863/how-to-deserialize-interface-fields-using-jacksons-objectmapper), but property = "type" inside Configuration, but I have outside. And because of it, I can't use `@JsonDeserialize` above property, because I have no information about `type`

Comment: Could you provide example `JSON` payload and `POJO` model?

Comment: It seems you should implement custom deserialization at the level of `Car` class where you select implementation of `Configuration` depending on `type` value.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following for serialize/deserialize polymorphic objects:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY)
@JsonSubTypes(
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = AlertRuleConfigurationDeserialize.class, name = "config")
)
public abstract class Car {

    private String type;
    private Configuration config;

}
```

Then, as an example, you can serialize/deserialize like:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        Configuration config = new AlertRuleConfigurationDeserialize();

        Car car = new Car("type",config);

        try {
            String carJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(car);

            System.out.println(carJson);

            Car deserializedCar = objectMapper.readValue(carJson, Car.class);

            System.out.println("Deserialized CarJson Class: " + deserializedCar.getClass().getSimpleName());

           
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @HayamiPysh does it helped you?