# Spring Boot REST endpoint returning interface (Serializing polymorphic type with Jackson)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have this working endpoint :

```
@GetMapping(value = "/my/path")
public Map<String, Collection<MyDataType>> getReport(...) {...}
```

It is consumes by an Angular frontend and works perfectly but now I need to return different types of MyDataType.
So I created an empty interface `MyData` and 2 classes `MyDataType1` and `MyDataType2`. To simplify, I use the Lombok annotations.

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class MyDataType1 implements MyData {
   private int number;
   private String value;
}
```

And update my endpoint:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/my/path"")
public Map<String, Collection<? extends MyData>> get20062008Report(
```

As a result, I get empty JSONs because Spring (I guess) doesn't see my object as a `MyDataType1` or a `MyDataType2`. But as a `MyData`.

[image: OK: The data structure with the subtypes]

[image: KO: What we see in Chrome]

**How can I override the serialization to force the transformation in JSON with the corresponding instance type ?**

Comment: I already tried JsonDeserializer (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-jsoncomponent)

Comment: I think you can take a look on something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19379863/how-to-deserialize-interface-fields-using-jacksons-objectmapper. if I get your question right :) We need some more information for mapper to deserialise by the interface

Comment: Thank you for your response Echoinacup
I followed the link you gave me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19379863/how-to-deserialize-interface-fields-using-jacksons-objectmapper.
But it was not my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I find the issue. It was due to the type I used. Jackson didn't suceed with the type `? extends MyData`.
So I replace:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/my/path"")
public Map<String, Collection<? extends MyData>> get20062008Report(
```

With:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/my/path"")
public Map<String, Collection<MyData>> get20062008Report(
```

And it now works perfectly:
[image: OK: With the interface type]

Comment: It also works when I change the return type for Map<String, Collection<Object>>.